# Where can I find the error with yum repository?

Tags: linux, repository, redhat, yum

I have not been able to find the answer to this question on the  other sites

I'm kind of perplexed by the lack of an error message when yum is checking the repo files is `/etc/yum.repos.d`

I have permanently mounted the RedHat ISO onto `/sr0` and I'm trying to use the repository in `/sr0/AppStream`

However when I place the repository file on `yum.repo.d`:

```
[AppStream]
name=AppStream
baseurl=file:///sr0/AppStream
enabled=1
```

and then I run `yum update`, I get the following message:

```
Problem Repository: [AppStream] 
bandwith:0
baseurl: file:///sr0/AppStream
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
cost: 1000
countme: 0
delarpm: 1
delarpm_percentage: 75
enabled: 1
...
```

But I get no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found what was happening.
apparently, there was a more detailed error message being output. It was just that I was unable to see it. Because I was in a non-graphical (multiuser.target) mode so I was unable to scroll up the terminal output. I was able to see the complete error message the I redirected the output to a file and then read it:

```
yum update  2> error_output.txt && less error_output.txt
```